# NET Native Tool Chain for UWP throws NotImplementedException in Portable Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

We have quite a large shared project, which has 3 heads so to speak:

- Windows.UWP
- Windows.Desktop81
- Windows.Phone81

These three each reference Portable Libraries which target both Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1.

When compiling the UWP project using the native tool chain, the portable libraries cannot access any type information so they can’t perform any reflection.

The method which is failing is a generic one, and inspects `typeof(T)` to do various operations depending on what type it is.

First line that throws an `System.NotImplementedException` is:

```
If (typeof(T).IsArray)
```

In this case, T is `System.String`, and if I break the debugger on the failing method and type into the immediate window of visual studio 2015, I get:

```
>> typeof(string).IsArray
An internal error has occurred while evaluating method System.Type.get_IsArray().
```

However, if I do the same in the App.OnLaunched method, that works fine. So the portable libraries cannot access any type information, even for system types like `System.String`.

I have tried adding platform directives for the Portable Libraries, but so far no luck.

Do you have any information regarding how to enable Portable Libraries to access type information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response back from Michal at Microsoft via email, explaining the root cause and how to get around it.

> You seem to be hitting the same issue described here:
>   https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/3565, except the method in
>   question is Type.IsArray instead of ConstructorInfo.Invoke.
>
> The problem is that the method Type.IsArray is declared as non-virtual
>   in the Portable Library contracts that your source code compiles
>   against, but it is virtual in the [implementation assemblies](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/6532e4708effb2d32891df1179312fac7a8afeb4/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Type.cs#L42) used in
>   .NET Native. This is normally not a big problem because the C#
>   compiler pretty much always uses “callvirt” instruction to call the
>   method (even if it’s not virtual). The C# compiler shipped in Visual
>   Studio 2017 started doing an optimization that if a method is not
>   virtual and **the 'this' passed to the method is known not to be null**,
>   it uses “call” instead of “callvirt”. The result is that the code ends
>   up calling a method that should never have been called. The result of
>   the typeof() expression is known to be never null.
>
> The good news is that we made IsArray [non-virtual again](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/2a42a6a9a0dcb8d7ea8e9a61d1db899bb08b46e2/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Type.cs#L36) as part of the
>   NetStandard 2.0 effort. The bad news is that .NET Native with support
>   for NetStandard 2.0 hasn’t shipped yet.
>
> You’ll need a workaround. The easiest I can think of is to add an
>   extension method and use that instead:
>
> ```
> static class NetNativeWorkarounds
> {
>     public static bool IsArray(this Type type) => type.IsArray;
> }
> ```
>
> Using the extension method avoids the C# compiler optimization because
>   **this condition** is not met (the compiler doesn’t know what type you’ll
>   pass to the extension method and has to do a callvirt to the
>   Type.IsArray method).